# Are dynamodb scans acceptable for fetching a list?

Tags: database, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb

Does it make sense to use a dynamodb scan, for example if one wants to list all items in a table?

For example, for an admin dashboard where all recent transaction items should be shown, or where the full user list should be shown?

Is there a way to avoid slowing down the database for other users while performing such large queries (by for example 'slowing down' the admin dashboard query on purpose as it is of lower importance than actual user's queries)?

Comment: This is opinionated but from a practical perspective, a scan would be the only way. The "does it make sense" is answered by - how many items do you have? Can you pay for it? Why are you using DynamoDB? Is NoSQL suitable for your application as a whole?

Comment: But as a whole, for "get all items" scenarios you most likely should not be using NoSQL and in particular, DDB. NoSQL is for fetching specific items and excels in speed there, not for searching/sorting/listing/filtering which SQL is perfect for (generally).

Comment: If all you need is getting all items, and the cost/performance is fine when testing, then yes it makes "sense". But most of the time, especially for a dashboard, you'll go down the road and get into so many blockers for searching/sorting etc. Look into Elasticsearch for example maybe or RDS for Postgres...

Comment: If you must use DynamoDB, then yes - to get all items, a scan is the only way as a query would not make sense (there is nothing to filter the data on).

Comment: If you have enough RCU provisioned (or are in On Demand mode) and you do a parallel scan then it will be quite fast as well and won't slow down other activity. It's really just about the cost of the scan, which is linear with table size.